# Tranduction: The English phrase "My loving spirit."

Tags: traduction

Context is the full phrase "cooking is an extension of my loving spirit".

"mon esprit d'amour"

or

"mon esprit qui aime"

Which one bests describes the spirit as "loving" rather than "of love" - or are these distinctions not relevant in the French language?

Comment: *Cuisiner est un prolongement de mon aimable gnôle* ;-) You should explain what precisely means "my loving spirit" in this sentence to those of us who are not familiar with this phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to translate literally then you can say "mon esprit aimant", where "aimant" is the present participle of the verb "aimer" (and not the noun meaning "magnet").

However, you shouldn't try to translate literally such "poetic" constructions, as it's likely to result in nonsense or unidiomatic sentences. For example, I doubt the sentence I wrote above is really good. You have to think hard of what you want to mean by "my loving spirit" and find the most idiomatic way of saying that idea in French. For example, if this is really about love, then you can say "ma cuisine est une extension de mon amour". Or if it's about generosity, then "ma cuisine est une extension de ma générosité (naturelle?)". And so on.